# How to avoid repetition in C# do-while loop?

Tags: c#, .net, do-while

I make a program that reads from user input and print on the console if it was a valid input, else will redo the operation.
I get to a solution but not with a perfect code, the code is repetitive.
I'm looking for solution with less code(clean) and same result. Thanks

```
        string str1, str2, str3, str4, str5;
        bool sucess1, sucess2, sucess3, sucess4, sucess5;
        int number1, number2, number3, number4, number5;
        long result;

        do
        {
            str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            sucess1 = int.TryParse(str1, out number1);
            if (sucess1) Console.WriteLine("Number is valid: {0}", number1);
            else Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number! please enter a whole number.");

        } while (sucess1 != true);

        do
        {
            str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            sucess2 = int.TryParse(str2, out number2);
            if (sucess2) Console.WriteLine("Number is valid: {0}", number2);
            else Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number! please enter a whole number.");

        } while (sucess2 != true);
```

Comment: Just create a method to factorize (cut/paste) and wall it twice with the needed ref/out parameter or get a return value ... https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+refactoring

Comment: [C# MSDoc](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp) | [Level 0](https://w3schools.in/csharp-tutorial) | [Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm) | [Level 2](https://tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-tutorials) | [Level 3](https://guru99.com/c-sharp-tutorial.html) | [Level 4](https://geeksforgeeks.org/csharp-programming-language) | [Linq 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) | [Linq 2](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/linq) | Beginning Visual C# 2008 Programming | Professional C# 7 and .Net Core 2.0 | Professional Visual Studio 2015 (Vol I) and 2017 (Vol II)

Comment: A small style point for beginners: instead of `success1 != true`, it's more idiomatic to say `!success`.  And similarly, avoid `x == true` in favor of simply `x`. You don't have to test if its true that true is equal to true.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're looking to avoid repetition. Generally, in this type of scenario you'll want to [extract](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractFunction.html) the common code. Here's an example of what you could do:

```
var  Numbers = new List<int>(); //We store every number in this list.

while(Numbers.Count < 5) //5, 10; however many numbers you want to store.
{
    if(TryReadFromConsole(out int Number)) //If we got a good number...
    {
        Numbers.Add(Number); // ... we add it to our list.
    }
}

//This is your common functionality.
static bool TryReadFromConsole(out int ParsedNumber) //Returns a bool, outputs the parsed number.
{
    var rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if(int.TryParse(rawInput, out ParsedNumber)) //If the number was OK, it'll be stored in our ouput variable.
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Number is valid: {ParsedNumber}");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number! Please enter a whole number.");
        return false;
    }
}
```